# Request for help: wrt a proof I've written. No rational $r$ satisfying $2^r = 3$

Tags: real-analysis, fake-proofs

I'll start off by requesting no one gives me a solution to this problem. I would just like some direction. Please let me know if I've made a mistake where I've gone wrong and if possible let me know 'why' what I have done is wrong.

Show that there is no rational number $r$ satisfying $2^r = 3$.

If $r$ is rational then we can write $r = a/b : a,b \in$ integers, and $b\neq0$

so, $$ 2^{a/b} = 3,$$
$$log_2(2)^{a/b} = log_2(3)$$
$$a/b=log_2(3)$$
$$a=b*log_2(3)$$

This means $a$ is a multiple of $log_2(3)$ so we can write, $a = m*log_2(3)$ where $m$ is an integer and $m \neq b $

$$m*log_2(3) = b*log_2(3)$$

dividing both sides by $log_2(3)$ gives $m = b$ which is a contradiction. (I think).
The logic behind $m \neq b$ is that m can be zero.

This entire thing I've done looks almost absurd though.

Anyways, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is $m=b$ a contradiction? $b$ is assumed an integer and $m$ is also an integer\

Comment: Well, if $m = b$, then $b$ can be $0$ since there are no restrictions on $m$. If $b = 0$ then $2^{a/b}$ Is undefined.

Comment: Now that I'm saying this though. It's making me realize I could have just off the bat said something like "assume $a = 0$ if $a = 0$ then $b = 0$ since $0 / log_2(3) = 0 $" I'm not very good at these proofs lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no contradiction in $m=b.$ The correct proof involves no log, and instead finds a contradiction in $2^a = 3^b.$

Comment: Thank you for the help.